# Bounds on Gaussian process posterior variance.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, asymptotics

This is in the context of Gaussian process models where, the posterior variance (given observations at $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$) has the following form $\sigma_n^2(x)=k(x,x) - \mathbf{k}(X, x)^T \mathbf{K}_n^{-1} \mathbf{k}(X, x)$, where $k(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a positive definite covariance kernel, $\mathbf{k}(X, x)$ is the vector $[k(x_1, x), \ldots, k(x_n, x)]$, and $\mathbf{K}$ is an $n\times n$ postive definite matrix defined as $\mathbf{K}_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$.

Are there any existing works that discuss the rate of convergence of $\sigma_n^2(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ or some sort of an upper bound, e.g., (for a finite $n$)
$\sigma_n^2(x) \leq \mathcal{O} ( \frac{1}{log(n)} )$?

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda late, but if you are still interested, the following references might be helpful.

1. Teckntrup A., "Convergence of Gaussian Process Regression with Estimated Hyper-parameters and Applications in Bayesian Inverse Problems" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00232)
2. Wynne et al., "Convergence Guarantees for Gaussian Process Means
   With Misspecified Likelihoods and Smoothness" (https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume22/20-662/20-662.pdf)